# How to get RStudio-stop icon in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rstudio

I have used to watch the red icon in RStudio showing that a script is being executed. It is very intuitive, clear, and handy as a stop button.

[Red stop icon in RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuUsX.png)

How can I get a similar icon in Visual Studio Code using the [R extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r), indicating the (R)terminal is running some code? Or are the missing `+` sings a reliable indicator of a running process? However, they do not work as a stop button, obviously.

The settings for the R extension do not give any relevant results with `@ext:REditorSupport.r stop` or `@ext:REditorSupport.r button`or `@ext:REditorSupport.r running`.